# Disadvantages to using NTFS as main storage drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, ntfs, fuse

I'm dual-booting with Windows 10. Right now, my partition setup is like this:

- 20GB /
- 10GB /home
- 70 GB "Linux stuff" (~/Downloads, ~/Documents, etc. all softlink to folders here)
- 300GB Windows (NTFS)

The problem is, sometimes there's lots of space in "Linux Stuff" with not much space in Windows, and sometimes the opposite is true.

What I'd like to do is to just merge the Linux-stuff and Windows partitions. I'd create a "linux" folder in the Windows partition, and softlink ~/Downloads, ~/Documents, ~/Pictures, and such there.

Are there any "gotchas" to doing this, using NTFS for most of my Linux files? In particular:

- Is the NTFS access stable?
- Is the NTFS access considerably slower than EXT?
- Are there any other hidden disadvantages to doing this? Does it interfere with indexing/searching of my files, open file dialogues, etc?

Comment: Well for one thing, *AFAIK*, not only does Linux **not** support NTFS permissions; it completely ignores them.

Comment: @AndroidDev Would that still be concern on a single-user system, i.e. a laptop with only one account?

Comment: Probably not...

Comment: That's understandable since NTFS has ACLs rather than file permissions. They are somehow similar but not the same thing.

Comment: Have you considered going the other way instead, and carving out a big partition for your data that's `ext2`, shrinking your Windows partition to just be what's required for the OS and programs itself, and installing an `ext2` driver for Windows so it can also access it?

Comment: The permissions/file types thing will bite you. When I tried this, every old Windows file of every kind was marked as executable, so every time you doubleclick to open a file, you get asked if you want to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You could link in a windows file system like that and it would work. Linux wouldn't have an issue.  The real issue you would run into is with windows if linux decided to rearrange the partition to accommodate incoming files.  It's rare but linux can break windows like this. I learned the hard way.

Why don't you just get a flash drive and use that?

Comment: Yeah, a 300GB flash drive... I'm looking to store my files, not just transfer some things back and forth.